# Algorithm used to segment undos when writing text in a browser textarea/input field

Tags: html, browser, textarea

What is the algorithm used to split the process of writing a text into undoable actions in Chrome or Firefox textarea?

Let's say I'm writing some text in the textarea of a webpage. Then I undo using ctrl/alt-z a few times. How is the amount of characters changed at every step calculated? Is it documented somewhere? Is it different in each browser?